# Book where government performs experiments on women who later have psychic children

Tags: story-identification

I read this series between late 90's and early 2000.

The government did psychic experiments on women. When they had kids, the kids ended up having some psychic abilities. I want to say the main character went by Rae and her boyfriend was Anthony but he went by Tony. They met at a support group and he was wearing a boyband shirt because his little sister got it for him for his birthday.

In addition, the girl could read the thoughts people had when they left their fingerprints and she spent some time in a mental hospital becuase when her ability started she thought she was going crazy and her mom had died some time after she was born.

I think it was published with [Alloy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alloy_Entertainment) but not sure. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Like @Edlothiad writes above, you can [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/158080/edit) your question to correct typos and add details, instead of leaving them as comments. Welcome to the site, by the way.

Answer (score 7):

The title would be [*Fingerprints*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0064472655), I think. I read it long ago, so I'm not so sure.

It is by Melinda Metz, and the name of the main protagonist, Rae, is right, if you can trust the amazon-recensions.

---

Under "From publishers Weekly":

> When Rae starts to hear voices in her head, she is convinced that she is slipping into insanity, just as her deceased mother had apparently done. After having what appears to be a breakdown in her high school cafeteria, Rae is temporarily hospitalized for paranoiac delusions. Given the title of both the series and the book, and the circumstances under which Rae hears the "not-her thoughts," their source soon becomes apparent to readers: whenever the teen touches an object, she experiences the thoughts of individuals who have touched it previously.

Comment: Can you provide snippets of the text that support some of the bits the Original Poster has remembered?